# Discord Python Bot: Searching for words in a Message

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have a little code for my Bot, which reacts (f.e.) with owo if someone writes uwu.
But I can only use if message.content.startswith("")
So, is it possible, to search for uwu/owo in the message (f.e. test uwu)?

Here's some code:

```
        if message.content.startswith("UwU"):
            await message.channel.send("OwO")
        if message.content.startswith("OwO"):
            await message.channel.send("UwU")
        if message.content.startswith("uwu"):
            await message.channel.send("owo")
        if message.content.startswith("owo"):
            await message.channel.send("uwu")
        if message.content.startswith("Uwu"):
            await message.channel.send("Owo")
        if message.content.startswith("uwU"):
            await message.channel.send("owO")
        if message.content.startswith("Owo"):
            await message.channel.send("Uwu")
        if message.content.startswith("owO"):
            await message.channel.send("uwU")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr in str`. See: https://stackabuse.com/python-check-if-string-contains-substring/

This searches the whole string not just the start. For example:

```
if 'UwU' in str(message.content):
    await message.channel.send("OwO")
```